# Is there a way to skip a before/after save/delete hook in certain cases?

Tags: parse-platform

Question is, is there a way to explicitly run a save/delete, etc. without triggering the established hook? Like a "skipHook" option or something. Example:

```
// HOOK: beforeDelete

Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete('Thing', function(request, response){ // STUFF // });



// FUNCTION: some other cloud function that will run an alternate delete behavior

Parse.Cloud.define('AltBeforeDeleteThing', function(request, response){
  var id = request.params.id;
  var thing = new Thing();
      thing.id = id;

  thing.destroy().then(function(){ // STUFF // });
  // Is there a way to skip the beforeDelete hook?

}
```

The `destroy()` in the cloud function will trigger the `beforeDelete` hook. But I've run into situations where it'd be nice to have exceptions so I can build alternate behaviors around some of these Ops.

The only way I can think of doing this is creating an `if (!master)` clause in the `beforeDelete` hook and using `master` any time I wanted to skip that code. But it feels like I'm cheating and that it will put me in a corner I can't escape down the road.

What's the correct practice to get around established hooks to define alternate behaviors around these Ops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but I'll answer.

- Create a skip_beforeSave field in the object, check if field exists then issue response.success().
  https://www.parse.com/questions/skip-beforesave

Comment: Eh. Thanks though. So the only way to do it is to have logic directly in the beforeSave looking for some flag. I was hoping for something that ACTUALLY skips the hook instead of passing through but this answer, being the only answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: I was looking for the same, unfortunately Parse has not matured enough to offer skipping cloud code functions, their reasoning being it impacts security - being able to skip validation functions from client side.